# Embedding Plotly Graphs in Rmarkdown, embedded in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, plotly, shinydashboard

I'm trying to produce a shiny app which, depending on user input, will display one of many pre-compiled html files (produced from Rmarkdown files) in browser. I've gotten this working, but I also wish to include plotly charts within these html files that will also display within the shiny app.

The plotly chart displays just fine in the html document. The html document embeds fine as before in the shiny application, but there's simply a blank space where the plotly chart should be. If the chart is simply produced using ggplot it appears without issue.

**Is there some way to have the plotly chart appear within the shiny app as it does for static R plots?**

Example markdown and shiny code is below.

**example.rmd**

````
---
title: "example markdown"
output: html_document
---

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r, echo=FALSE, warnings = FALSE}
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggplot2))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(plotly))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggthemes))

plot_raw <- ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_hc()

p <- ggplotly(plot_raw)
p
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

#### Server Code ####

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$test <- renderUI(includeHTML("example.html"))

}

#### UI Code ####


header <- dashboardHeader(title = "plotly test")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(

  sidebarMenu(id="menu1",

              menuItem("tab 1", 
                       tabName = "tab1", 
                       icon = icon("desktop")),

              menuItem("tab 2", 
                       tabName = "tab2", 
                       icon = icon("dashboard")),

              conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.menu1 == 'tab2'",
                selectInput("choice", "Select from choices", 
                            choices = c(1,2,3))
                )
              )
  )

body <- dashboardBody(


  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.menu1 == 'tab2'",
    fluidPage(

      htmlOutput('test')

    )
  )
  )

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: why don't you use renderPlotly({ }) in your server.R file to produce the plotly plot? Why do you need the RMarkdown doc?

Comment: To allow other users to easily update the information associated with each markdown doc. These will change overtime and whilst updating of a markdown doc is fairly straightforward, digging into the shiny code in order to carry out each update would be less so. It also easily handles printing of the documents with a pdf version of the document stored in the same location. It's definitely not the most direct solution but it seems the best from a maintenance/update point of view.

Comment: I run your code as is, and got an html doc with the plotly graph well displayed with no errors. Could you include your `sessionInfo()` in the question?

Comment: On a separate note, I imagine you want to make your dashboard interactive using Shiny at the end? In this case, you have to add `runtime: shiny` in the YAML front matter of your markdown doc.